# Extract a number from a column with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to extract only `bash script_c.sh` process' number, from this output:

```
11545 pts/3    S+     0:00 bash script_c.sh
11625 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep script_c.sh
```

in this case it will be: `11545`

I have tried

```
PROCESS=$(ps ax | grep 'bash script_c.sh' | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d ' ' | sed '/^$/d')
```

After that I have to kill it using `kill $PROCESS`, but it doesn't work well, it says: "must be a pid of a job etc...".

Comment: It is also the first column.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the result of `echo $PROCESS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic tool for **extracting columns** is `cut`.

```
pgrep -fl 'bash script_c.sh' | cut -f1 -d" "
```

will extract the first column, separated by single space characters. It should actually do what you wanted. The bigger trick however was that I used `pgrep`, which has a much nicer output. If I hadn't added the `-l` switch, there would have been no need to `cut`:

```
pgrep -f 'bash script_c.sh'
```

However, for your particular task, you may want to just use `pkill`.

It allows killing processes by a pattern, e.g.

```
pkill -f "script_c.sh"
```

The big benefit is that `pgrep` and `pkill` are aware of themselves, and will only output/kill matching *other* processes. In your above example, you will have false positives such as the `grep` command for example. So just use `pkill` which should be available on any modern Linux/BSD system.

If you really want to use `ps` (which I do not recommend):

```
 ps ax | grep script_c.sh | grep -v grep | sed -e 's/^ *\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/'
```

or even better with awk (which is better at automatically parsing the column layout of ps):

```
  ps ax | awk '!/awk/ && /script_c.sh/ { print $1 }'
```

Note that for both you have to make sure you don't match yourself, i.e. exclude grep and awk from matching. So using `pgrep` is substantially simpler. Both `pgrep` and `pkill` are the right tools for your actual problem.

Comment: pkill works like a charm and cut is perfect to extract first column thanks

Comment: One additional handy script is to do `|grep '[s]cript_c.sh` which will match the process but not match the grep.

Comment: @AlanShutko cute hack, but using `pgrep` obviously is much nicer. :-)

Comment: It is, but it's not everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PROCESS=$(ps ax | grep 'bash script_c.sh' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
```